# how to use required in input

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this input field

```
<td>
    <input class="task-input" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.TaskDescription" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
    ng-change="addActionButtons(workflow)" placeholder="Task" />
</td>
```

This field must be filled in each row and user cant fill next row while this field is empty. How to use `required` or `ng-required` in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-required="true" inside input tag.

```
 <td>
    <input class="task-input" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.TaskDescription" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
    ng-change="addActionButtons(workflow)" placeholder="Task" ng-required="true" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html `required` property as

```
<input class="task-input" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.TaskDescription" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
ng-change="addActionButtons(workflow)" placeholder="Task" required />
```